# How do you assign the printThis plugin function to a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, printthis

Sorry for the noob question...I've been searching for an example but I'm obviously doing something wrong (or am way off track in what I want to do!)

I am using this:
http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/10483/0/page/2
to create a multipage form using visibility and div sections.  Seems to work very well.

I now need to be able to print (printer) one page from another page.  Possible?

I'm trying to use the printThis plugin by Jason Day.

I am calling the plugin like so:
$.getScript("printThis.js", function(){
});

(plugin is in the current directory...will address that later)

```
<input type="button" id="B1" value="Go Back" onClick="showLayer('page1')">
<input type="button" id="B2" value="Print App" onClick="$("#page1").printThis()">
```

First button works as expected...goes back to page1
Second button does nothing...is syntax right?  Or am I just trying to do something that can't be done?

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question.

Comment: Hmm...I did include it but the interface appears to have deleted it upon posting...I am new to StackOverflow as well...still learning...give me a minute and I will get it plugged back in

Comment: OK...as I said...learning even the StackOverflow interface!  Did not indent the code section...sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first <kbd>button</kbd> is correct. The second <kbd>button</kbd> is not however. Your double quotes `"` within your jQuery selector is causing the `onClick` attribute to close prematurely. Try one of the following methods:

**Inline Option 1 - Escape Double Quotes**

```
<input type="button" id="B2" value="Print App" onClick="$(\"#page1\").printThis()">
```

**Inline Option 2 - Use Single Quotes**

```
<input type="button" id="B2" value="Print App" onClick="$('#page1').printThis()">
```

**Option 3 - Remove Obtrusive JavaScript (Strongly Recommended)**

```
<!-- Place this code in the <head></head> section of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#B2').on('click', function () {
            $('#page1').printThis();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I used Inline option 1 -- that seems to have solved the printThis function trigger issue.  However...I only got 2 blank pages!  This is probably a completely unrelated issue from my original question...

Comment: @user3066388 Does `page1` exist on the current page?

Comment: I have figured out that this really is unrelated to my original question...original question regarding the syntax of calling the plugin was answered and it works now.  I will post a new question regarding the blank page print since it really goes off in another direction...thanks all!

Comment: I'm the printThis author. Option 3 is the correct answer, as you should avoid inline javascript, as it's not a good or maintainable coding standard.